# Installed one 32-bit program, now everything is 32-bit?

Tags: apt, wine

In trying to get Steam to work, someone recommended I do `apt install steam:i386`. Now, when I got to install `winetricks` via `apt install winetricks`:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fuseiso glib-networking:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer1.0-x:i386 i965-va-driver:i386
  intel-media-va-driver:i386 libaa1:i386 libaom0:i386 libaribb24-0:i386
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
  libasyncns0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libavc1394-0:i386 libavcodec-extra58:i386
  libavutil56:i386 libblkid1:i386 libbrotli1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386
  libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3
  libcapi20-3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcom-err2:i386
  libcups2:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdb5.3:i386
  libdbus-1-3:i386 libdv4:i386 libexif12:i386 libfaudio0 libfaudio0:i386
...
```

and so on.

Is this a pecularity with wine (i.e., expected behavior, to have a ton of 32-bit dependencies) or did I just break `apt`?

Comment: I just told it to install *one* `i386` package. I didn't use `--add-architecture`. Those are two totally separate operations... but I wouldn't be surprised if you're right anyway. Linux moment.

Comment: I don't want to do something like `apt purge *:i386` or whatever is the equivalent, surely that will fry my install completely? There's gotta be at least one natural 32-bit dependency *somewhere* in there that will break something.

Comment: A 32-bit (i386) package may have *depends* rules on other i386 package, as the amd64 packages likely use different ABI/APIs are of no benefit, so adding a single i386 package on an amd64 would be expected to install many other packages (where API/ABI doesn't match the 64-bit or larger interfaces)

Comment: I'm aware that i386 packages will depend on others of the same architecture - I'm saying, why would asking to install 32-bit Steam and its dependencies count as an instruction to `apt` to now install everything 32-bit? What is going on here?

Comment: If I said `apt install somepackage:i386` I would expect to see many i386 deps. Why would installing regular `winetricks` on an AMD64 system start downloading a ton of i386 stuff, just because *one time* I asked for *one i386 package*? More importantly, how does a person resolve this?